# vba code to find a predetermined range, copy and transpose

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a excel document with multiple seperate data, all in a single column (A1 to A10160).

All the data begins in a cell with the text NC/xx/xxxx/x (x being variable) and ending in a cell containing different dates but the cell above it always has the text "Start Date". Some data covers 49 cells others cover 51 cells so it's not contained in a fixed number of cells in the column.

I need to copy the range from NC/xx/xxxx/x to Start Date plus one for each data "set", transpose it and paste all the data in the column in a new sheet.

Really haven't found anything useful so far but I am fumbling with this one:

```
Sub Find()
Dim Search, End, Start, i As Integer, j As Integer, L
    Search = Cells(1, 1)
    End = Cells(2, 1)
    For i = 1 To 10160
        If Left(Cells(i, 1), 3) = Search Then
            Start = i - 0
        End If
    Next i
    For j = 1 To 10160
    If Cells(j, 1) = End Then
            L = j + 1
        End If
            Sheet4.Select
            Range(Cells(Start, 1), Cells(L + 2, 1)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheet4.Range("BB23").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End
    Next j
    
End Sub
```

Would really appreciate any help I can get!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like  you haven't had much interest in your question, so I've taken a look at it.  It's one of those *fiddly* jobs - not terribly technical but tricky to get the flow of logic right.  The code below gives you what you've outlined in your question.  You've said `transpose it` - so that's what the code does. Try it and let me know how you go.

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub Copy2Sheet2()
    'Declare all your variables
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim topRow As Long, BottomRow As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim PasteToRow As Long, i As Long, c As Range
    
    'Set the sheet variables
    Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = Sheets(2)
    
    'Initial row settings
    LastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    PasteToRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 '<~~ assumes headers on sheet2
    
    'Start the loop
    For i = 1 To LastRow   
        'Find the bottom row of the first block of data
        Set c = ws1.Range("A" & i & ":A" & LastRow).Find(What:="Start Date", LookIn:=xlValues)
        BottomRow = c.Row + 1    
    
        'Define and copy the range to sheet2
        ws1.Range("A" & i & ":A" & BottomRow).Copy
        ws2.Range("A" & PasteToRow).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
            'Redefine the 'paste to' row
            PasteToRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
            'Redefine the top row of the next block of data
            i = BottomRow
    
    'Repeat the process
    Next i
    
    End Sub
```